# Segfault stacktrace doesn't contain source

Tags: c++, gdb, sdl

Using gdb with eclipse, I'm getting a segfault and none of my thread stacktraces contain my source files.
This is with SDL, I believe SDL is the threads >1, while Thread 1 is my only one.

[image: screenshot]

[gdb trace](http://pastebin.com/Wd13SFec)

using gcc flags -std=c++1y -O0 -ggdb3

Even before I had this issue, gdb always crashes when the program terminates normally when ran in debug mode. Don't know if related.

Although I have been able to figure out the approximate area in my code where it occurs by commenting things out; I would like to know what is wrong independent of code so that I can use gdb properly.

Edit: It was a newb mistake of creating non-copied shared_ptr. So the crash is caused by a double freeing. Still doesn't explain the useless debug info however.

Comment: Have you tried running your code through valgrind?

Comment: Have you been linking to the debug version of SDL?

Comment: @shuttle87 im on windows

Comment: @VermillionAzure ive been dynamic linking, will try that